# Is it possible in Gitlab to copy or import one bare repo to another bare repo?

Tags: gitlab

We use Gitlab in our project and we are planning to decommission the VM where our current GItlab is hosted and to move on to a different VM.

Is it possible to copy or duplicate the exact current set-up into our new VM along with its branches, tags and history? if so, could you pls. help me on the same.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
This is what we did in our migration:

1.- In the new VM, clone the repo from the old VM.
cd /home/git/repositories/[your-namespace]/
git clone --bare git@old-git-vm:namespace/repo.git

2.- chown -R git:git repo.git
chmod 770 repo.git

3.- Import repos to Gitlab
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production